# Trying to build gstreamer sharp, return error on 'make'-command

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, gstreamer

I'm trying to build gstreamer sharp so that I can use it in monodevelop. I follow the (simple) instructions provided on the github-page, but it gives an error on the make-command.

This is the github project and instructions: https://github.com/xDarkice/gstreamer-sharp

And this is the output in the terminal:

```
Making all in sources
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/magnus/Downloads/GStreamer/gstreamer-sharp-master/sources'
/usr/bin/gmcs -nowarn:169 -unsafe -target:library -r:/usr/lib/pkgconfig/../../lib/mono/gtk-sharp-3.0/glib-sharp.dll   \
        AssemblyInfo.cs custom/*.cs  generated/*.cs -out:../out/gstreamer-sharp.dll
AssemblyInfo.cs(25,12): warning CS1699: Use compiler option `keyfile' or appropriate project settings instead of `AssemblyKeyFile' attribute
custom/Caps.cs(31,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Structure' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
custom/FFTF32.cs(33,139): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `FFTF32Complex' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
custom/FFTF32.cs(35,45): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `FFTF32Complex' does not exist in the namespace `Gst.FFT'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
custom/FFTF32.cs(42,48): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `FFTWindow' does not exist in the namespace `Gst.FFT'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
custom/Iterator.cs(40,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `IteratorResult' does not exist in the namespace `Gst'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
custom/NavigationQuery.cs(23,41): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Query' does not exist in the namespace `Gst'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
custom/NavigationQuery.cs(23,58): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `NavigationCommand' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
custom/TagList.cs(55,24): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `TagMergeMode' does not exist in the namespace `Gst'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
custom/Value.cs(456,10): error CS0104: `DateTime' is an ambiguous reference between `System.DateTime' and `GLib.DateTime'
/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/../../lib/mono/gtk-sharp-3.0/glib-sharp.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
custom/Value.cs(476,16): error CS0104: `DateTime' is an ambiguous reference between `System.DateTime' and `GLib.DateTime'
/usr/lib/mono/2.0/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/../../lib/mono/gtk-sharp-3.0/glib-sharp.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Compilation failed: 10 error(s), 1 warnings
make[1]: *** [../out/gstreamer-sharp.dll] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/magnus/Downloads/GStreamer/gstreamer-sharp-master/sources'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong repository. gstreamer-sharp has moved to http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-sharp with a mirror on github at https://github.com/gstreamer-sharp/gstreamer-sharp